# Phonegap iOS Iframe access

Tags: ios, html, iframe, cordova, same-origin-policy

### Accessing an iframe in iOS from PhoneGap

I have a hard time getting PhoneGap(2.9.0) to access an iframe on iOS (6.0.1).

The index.html of the application consists of an iframe and a function to check if I can read the content of the frame after its loaded.

**Application index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, 
     maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, 
     target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="./phonegap.js"></script>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: #000;">
    <iframe name="framewrap" id="framewrap"
        style="border:0;position: absolute; top: 0; 
        left: 0;width: 100%; height:100%; background-color: #fff;"
        src="http://www.somedomain.de/somepath/index.html">
    </iframe>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.setTimeout(go, 2000);
      function go(){
      iframe = document.getElementById('framewrap');
      innerDoc = iframe.contentWindow;
      alert(innerDoc.document.getElementById('canvas'));
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**The document within the iframe:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      alert('iframe loaded');
    </script>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body style="margin:0;">
  <canvas id="canvas" style="position: absolute; top:0; left:0;">
    <p>Your browser does not support the canvas element.</p>
  </canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

**What happens:**

If I build the application and run it on Android(4.2.2) the frame is loaded, one alert tells me `iframe loaded` and another alert dialog pops up telling me there is an `HTMLCanvasElement`.
However if I open the app on an iPod Touch I just get an alert dialog telling me `"null"`.
The absence of the `iframe loaded` alert indicating the iframe is not loaded at all.

I have tried a lot of things to get this working but failed and since I don't own a mac I am not able to debug things right. *-thx apple-*

**What I suspect:**

The html file which is bundled with the app is executed as a file and uses the `file` protocol. The iframe uses the `http`protocol. Hence the same origin policy kicks in and I cant access the iframe.

**Why I am not sure:**

But that would mean inconsistent behavior across platforms since it is working on Android. So I am not fully convinced that my suspicion is correct.
Furthermore the lack of the `iframe loaded` alert would hint that the same-origin-policy is not the problem because at least the frame should load as it does on the desktop where the same-origin-policy only prevents the canvas alert to show.

**Therefore:**

1. Is my suspicion correct?
2. Is there a way to make it work across platforms?

I am thankful for any advice and hope someone can help me.

Thanks for taking the time to read trough!

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in iframe, but I'll give you a hint .. Use the load function of jquery out instead of iframe (http://api.jquery.com/load/) or a GET you can return the html-shaped return data and display in a div ...

Maybe it is a simpler alternative to iframe you are trying to mount ...

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tried getting data through ajax and other means. iOs blocks these unfortunately.

Comment: The error that the will not be in a cross domain webservice call?

I do not know what language you are using to create the webservices, but in php would look like:

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); header('Content-Type: application/json');